# wordpress contact form 7 is not sending email with attachment of file more than 7mb

Tags: forms, file, limit, attachment, contacts

I have used a contact form 7 form with an attachment field in one of my wordpress websites. The form is working properly (sending mail) when the attached file size (image) is less than 7mb. But If I attach a image file of more than 7mb, the mail is not being sent. Even any error message is not showing, just the processing cycle icon is rotating. just the processing icon is rotating. But, I have set the limit to 15mb.

Here is my attachment field:

```
<p>Attachment (required)<br />
[file file-866 limit:15mb] </p>
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **php.ini configuration** for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings, increase these if neccessary. Remember to restart your server after changing configuration.

If it doesn't solve the issue, then turn on `WP_DEBUG_LOG` by adding following line to **wp-config.php** file

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Now try again to upload large file and check the debug.log file from **/wp-content/** to detect the problem.

Comment: This is my php.ini file:
post_max_size = 32M
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 32M
allow_url_fopen = On
user_agent="PHP"
default_socket_timeout = 300`

Comment: I think the php.ini setting is fine.

I have also enabled the 'WP_DEBUG_LOG'. And the checked the debug.log file. The following two messages are repeting:

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant n_theme_name_scripts - assumed 'n_theme_name_scripts' in /home/ykinnor/public_html/wp-content/themes/trading/functions.php on line 39
[20-Apr-2017 10:28:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ykinnor/public_html/wp-content/themes/trading/functions.php:39) in /home/ykinnor/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1171

Comment: Could you please find out anything from this?

Comment: No such file debug.log in wp-content even after some actions or cf7 file upload